# Setting different subnet address as gateway IP in Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu

I like to know is there a way to set different subnet address as gateway address in ubuntu.

Brief descr :: I have  a ubuntu machine with interface IP eth0 as 10.213.17.0/29 (fall in 10.213.0.0 network)..i want to set 10.213.63.254 as a default gateway IP (10.213.63.254 is fall in different subnet 10.213.33.0 network)..If i configure in ubuntu machine using 'route add' command i got an error message of "Network is not reachable"..Please guide is it possible to set default gw as differnet network address.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible as the gateway is used to get to other networks/sub-networks.
The easy way to see this is:

You are at `Home`(192.168.0.10) and you want to go to the `cinema`(1.2.3.4), but, if you don't know that you firstly need to go through the door(gateway), you won't be able to get anywhere else but `Home`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.. i was checking with JUNOS .. it is supported it seems.. we should use 'resolve'command while adding static route - so once the route s nt reachable .. rt will check it own routing table & if by any means the gw is reachable ..it will fwd the packet frm ther